# Blackberry persistance: ObjectGroup createGroup vs. createGroupIgnoreTooBig

Tags: blackberry, persistence, grouping

What is the difference between the createGroup and createGroupIgnoreTooBig?

I understand that createGroup will throw the *too big* exception when the object exceeds 64k, and createGroupIgnoreTooBig will not. But does it mean that createGroupIgnoreTooBig allows me to create objects larger than 64k, or will it only partially group it?